# Why isn't this directory being added to my PATH when I use sudo?

Tags: sudo, root, path

I've just compiled and installed the Apache web server from sources, and now I want to add the `apachectl` script to `PATH`.

I know I need to add the directory to the `root` user's `PATH` (as the script needs to be run as root), so I thought I would try adding the line:

- file: `/root/.bashrc`

```bash
#
# add directory of apachectl to PATH
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/apache2/bin
```

I know the path I added is correct, but if I run the command:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

I get:

```
sudo: apachectl: command not found
```

how can I add this directory to my `PATH`?

Comment: Your .bashrc variables are getting updated by someone else.
Try mentioning same in `/etc/profile`

Comment: thanks, I added the line to  `/etc/profile` and then ran `source /etc/profile` which then enabled tab autocomplete (which is awesome!) but I still get the command not found when I run `sudo apachectl stop`

Comment: @user4668401 `sudo` probably uses a restricted PATH, check `sudoers` to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way to add a directory to sudo's `PATH` (which, as you found out is *not* the same as root's), is to edit the `sudoers` file:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then, find this line:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

And add your directory to the end of it:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/apache2/bin"
```

Alternatively, you could just create symlinks of the executables you want to run and place them in `/usr/local/bin` directly:

```
sudo find /usr/local/apache2/bin -type f -executable -exec ln -s {} /usr/local/bin/
```

Adding an alias for `sudo` that exports your environment works but is kind of inelegant and, more importantly, only works for one user.

Comment: I'd rather create that symlink in `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/bin`. The latter should be reserved for packages installed by the package manager.

Comment: @nyuszika7h well, technically, `apache` was installed by the package manager but it's up to the personal preferences of the sysadmin. Anyway, fair enough, answer edited.

Comment: agreed, alias = bad solution.  `sudo visudo` works great, thanks!